# How to make text/elements visible only in editor view in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010

I'm creating a template document for a client in Word 2010.
I'm trying to implement some instructions in the document, so that if the file is either printed or exported as a .pdf file, those instructions are not available/visible.

Comments are quite nice visually speaking, but unfortunately I can't find a way to avoid them to be printed or be visible when exporting the document to .pdf.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: It might help to explain why the instructions are needed in the document itself, but unwanted in the PDF or printed version--if nothing else, to give people an idea what might be a feasible workaround.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck It's a word document with some explanation on how to use some tables in it to create a spreadsheet report, nothing really fancy. Having those instructions visible inside a exported .pdf file or printed is not very nice!
As stated below my client is not very tech savvy, written notes inside the file is the most reliable way to hand instructions (already tried with instructions in a separate file or hand written notes. Been there, done that. No good results |: ).

Answer (score 2):

It's nasty, but AFAIK the only way to do it without trying to control print/save/export functions with macros is like this. Put the following nested fields in your doument:

```
{ IF { PRINTDATE \@YYYYMMDDhhmm } <> { DATE \@YYYYMMDDhhmm } "your instructions" }
```

where all the {  } are the special field code brace pairs that you insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word.

The instructions will disappear when doing both printing and PDF export. But they won't re-display until the user re-executes the field code (select and F9), and they'll have to wait for up to a minute before that will work. (PRINTDATE doesn't record seconds so using YYYYMMDDhhmmss does not help).

IMO a problem with any kind of conditional text in Word is that the document may need to repaginate whenever it disappears or reappears.

Comment: Looks interesting, but unfortunately that kind of task is something I already know will be a compilation for my client which is not quite tech savvy.. I'll give it a spin and see if it is practical to use for him. +1 for the tip tho can be useful!

Comment: @Gruber, yes, IMO this would only be "easy" if the feature was built into Word and (these days) the .docx specification.

Answer (score 0):

Comments can be hidden before printing. (On the *Review* tab, in the *Tracking* section, select **Final**.) Word 2010 also gives you a warning before saving or printing that a document contains comments, so that should prompt your user to double check to make sure comments are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could hyperlink certain phrases of text that either link to an external document/webpage with instructions or just simply insert an instruction in the ScreenTip so they display an instruction when hovered over.

The style of the hyperlinks can be modified so they are to be inconspicuous but still prompt your user to hover over them.